# Find end of class in string

Tags: python

**General description:**
Firstly:
I need to create hundreds of modules that get data from an API. The modules will have similar structure for the most part, but some elements will vary (their methods for example).

Secondly: 
Many of those modules will have to be edited later on (for example, change a method in a module).

Therefor
I created a program that:

- opens a module (in write mode),
- searches an object (for example a method) and determines where it starts and where it ends.
- Then replaces the object with something else.

**code example**

```
# I want to edit module_1 to module_100 and change their cook_method to bake_method.
# Below is the code for only one of the 100 modules.

with open('module_1.py', 'w+') as file:
    old = file.read()

    # method_loc is a function that returns a dict,
    # containing start and end of the method i wanted to edit.
    location_dct = method_loc(name='cook_method', string=old)

    # change cook_method to bake_method
    new = old[:location_dct['end']] + bake_method_as_string + old[location_dct['start']:]
    file.write(new)
```

**Problem:**
Detecting the exact location where the class ends is quite hard. I used string methods to create the methods for that, but it feels too complicated and sloppy. I searched and found the [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) which might make the above easier.

Also found [pyclbr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pyclbr.html?highlight=pyclb#module-pyclbr) which would be great if it could give me the line where a class ends, but it doesn't.

**Questions**

- Is there a better way to find where a class (or method or function or dict) ends inside a module that is opened as a string?
- Is the above functionality already available in some library?
- Is there a different way to do all the above?

Comment: I'd suggest modifying the code via a syntax tree, not as a plain text, for example, something that uses [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) or [`rope`](http://rope.sourceforge.net/)/[`traad`](https://github.com/abingham/traad).

Comment: I would approach the problem in different way. If these modules are created to aggregate data. I would recommend to store them in a database (with specific fields), then query the data directly from DB.

Comment: @bereal I have no idea what syntax trees are. 

What is the problem with the plain text?

Would it be worth the time to learn about STs compared to continue working on the subject with plain text?

Comment: @J.Smith the problem with plain text is that it's much harder to analyze in general. However, it's just came to me: since you're generating those modules yourself, you can add special comments like `#CLASSBEGIN MyClass`, `#CLASSEND MyClass` and search for them.

Comment: @bereal `#CLASSEND` would work but i have to do the same for dictionaries, methods, or dictionaries inside dictionaries etc. (I focused mostly on classes in my original question so that it's easier to explain what i need.) 

Also, although it may sound silly.. it wouldnt look "pretty" when i check those modules manually.

Comment: @J.Smith as I updated my answer: if that's you who generates the code, you can just re-generate the new version with new parameters without touching the old one at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write regular expressions to match the entire module at first. Make a pattern by re.compile and match it with properly placed parentheses to get the matched text. Then you can search for the method name again using pattern matching and once you reach correct place apply modification. You can also use PLY. Check a book on compilers for quick intro to regular expression.
Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Do I understand correct that you're suggesting parsing Python with regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's better to deal with the parsed version of the code, which is [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). That's more reliable, simple etc, and Python has the [standard module for that](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html).

However, since you're dealing with quite special case (you only need to replace a class and that's the code you generate yourself), you can label the code with comments like:

```
#CLASSBEGIN MyClass

class MyClass:
     ...

#CLASSEND MyClass
```

That way, you don't need to parse the code. As far as I remember, few code-generating tools use this approach.

Another way is to generate the code using a template engine, like [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/), so you don't need to modify the generated class, you'd just update the parameters and re-generate the new version.

Finally, in many cases you can try to minimize the amount or totally get rid of dynamically generated code by the proper objects decomposition.